# After the added product is updated and edited, another new detail page will be generated, but the original modified page was not updated

Tags: python, django

```
Python              3.8.3
Django              2.2
asgiref             3.3.1
djangorestframework 3.11.1
Pillow              7.2.0
pip                 19.2.3
psycopg2            2.8.6
pytz                2020.1
setuptools          41.2.0
sqlparse            0.3.1
```

May I ask the great god,
The newly added product object needs to be edited, but after editing it becomes another addition.
For example:
Enter the item 3 product, edit the content and click "Confirm Edit". The original item is the item number 3 and instantly becomes the item item No. 4. After each edit or update, it will become a new product page. What is the program part? Is there a mistake?

Add again:
Originally wanted to edit this page `http://127.0.0.1:8001/store/107/(id=107)`,
After editing and archiving, the page that pops up is a new id=111 page.
`http://127.0.0.1:8001/store/111/ (id=111)`

But I enter admin `http://127.0.0.1:8001/admin/store/product/111/change/`
After the change, there is no problem, and you can edit it. This error only appears on the screen of my newly created form.

Find a solution:
There is a similar "editing" program on the Internet. The writing method is similar to what I wrote, but I cannot edit the product with id=107. How can I solve it?

urls.py

```
    path('<int:id>/edit/', views.productUpdate, name='edit'),
```

views.py

```
def productUpdate(request, id=None):
    # basic use permissions 基本使用權限
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    instance = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
    form = ProductForms(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "<a href='#'>Item</a> Saved", extra_tags='html_safe')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    # 購物車購買數量
    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']

    context = {
        'instance': instance,
        'form': form,
        'cartItems': cartItems,
    }
    return render(request, 'store/form.html', context)
```

models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.TextField(default='')
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to=imgs,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        width_field="width_field",
        height_field="height_field"
    )
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try:
            url = self.image.url
        except:
            url = ''
        return url

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('store:detail', kwargs={'id': self.id})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]
```

form.html

```
{% extends "store/main.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="container">
         <div class="row pt-5">
            <div class='col-sm-6 pt-5'>
                <a href="{% url 'store:store' %}" class="pt-5 text-danger bg-dark text-decoration-none">返回首頁</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <h1>Form</h1>

                <form method='post' action='{% url 'store:create' %}' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button><input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Create Post'/></button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

{% endblock content %}
```

detail.html

```
            <div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
                <a href="{% url 'store:edit' id=instance.id %}">Edit/update Product</a><br>
                <a href="{% url 'store:delete' id=instance.id %}">Del Product</a><br>
                {#                <a href="{% url 'store:list' %}">Product</a><br>#}
            </div>
```

Important notice, because this is not an error message, neither the ide nor the webpage provides any error message, so it is not attached.

> Novice practice complete project : **https://github.com/georgiawang5332/libshopapp**

please help me thank you!!!

Comment: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/jSDpSGpF5c/

****Click the link to see more views.py code information***

I’m sorry for the trouble. I don’t know how to modify the content of stackoverflow. I will attach this link for your convenience. Thank you.

Comment: In fact, there is no error information report on my screen. Edit (updated) has also become the role of create and added another new object product. As a result, I cannot find the problem. There is no error backtracking.

I don't know where the problem is, I also put the practice project on github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a new object instead of updating the existing one:
Hope this will solve your problem.

```py
def productUpdate(request, id=None):
    # basic use permissions 基本使用權限
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    context = {}
    if request.POST:
        form = ProductForms(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = get_object_or_404(Product, id=id)
            form = ProductForms(data=request.POST, instance=instance)
            form.save()
            # updating our context
            context.update({'instance': instance})
            # message success
            messages.success(request, "<a href='#'>Item</a> Saved",
                             extra_tags='html_safe')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    else:
        form = ProductForms()  # if request isn't POST we initialize an empty form

    data = cartData(request)
    cartItems = data['cartItems']

    context.update({
        'form': form,
        'cartItems': cartItems,
    })
    return render(request, 'store/form.html', context)
```

Visit [django's modelform docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/) for more detail.

Comment: thank you your explanation for django ...

but i have this also wrong

<form method='post' action='{% url 'store:edit' id=instance.id %}' enctype='multipart/form-data'>{% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <button><input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Create Post'/></button>
</form>