# How to solve user updating problem in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I created a system with Django. I need user update section for this project. At the beginning of the project the user change form was working but now it doesnt work. I have a hiden field in my form and I think that's the problem but I'm not sure. Can you help me?

**view.py**

```
def update_user(request, id):

    user = get_object_or_404(UserProfile, id=id)
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'form': form,
    }

    return render(request, "update_user.html", context)
```

**models.py**

```
class UserProfile(AbstractUser):
    ranks = (
        ('Analyst', 'Analyst'),
        ...
        ('Chief Financial Officer', 'Chief Financial Officer'),
    )
    comp_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    user_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4(), editable=False, unique=True)
    ....
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=ranks)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_image', blank=True, null= True, default='profile.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    def get_unique_slug(self):
        slug = slugify(self.slug.replace('ı', 'i'))
        unique_slug = slug
        counter = 1
        while UserProfile.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
            unique_slug = '{}-{}'.format(slug, counter)
            counter += 1
        return unique_slug
```

**forms.py**

```
class SignUpChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (
            'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'rank', 'comp_name', 'image'
        )

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.clean_password
```

**update_user.html**

```
<form method="post">
                     {{ form|crispy }}
                        {% if form.errors %}
                        {% for field in form %}
                            {% for error in field.errors %}
                                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                    <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                                </div>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}

                     {% csrf_token %}
                     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                 </form>
```

[Error in the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMmIH.png)

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does its not showing or not saving your data?

Comment: Don't save my data

Comment: Have a look at [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65845839/11753731). The reason your form isn't saving is that you are not saving it in right way.